# Error:(30) Tag <category> attribute name has invalid character ' '

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-manifest

my app was running successfully but suddenly i got an error in debug/manifest file
Error:(30) Tag  attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is my debug/manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon_48"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name=" android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.ContactUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme1.Base"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.CareGiver"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_members_list" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.Testimonials"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_testimonials"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.AskAssistant"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ask_assistant"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme1.Base"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.Newsroom"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_newsroom" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.Resources"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_resources" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.HomeCare"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_care" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.Dash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_dash" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.CardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.NewDash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.solution.caring.caringsolutions.NewCard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Try This--> File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: i already tried this ,but it won't help me

Comment: Remove space from <category android:name=" android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: just try to restart everything.. restart your pc.. :)

Comment: @Gaskoin  yeah.. it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Courtesy** goes to ***@Gaskoin*** .

Remove Extra **space** from `category` .That's why have problem .

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Invalidate Caches/Restart` - that's pointless, plain `Run app` will be enough.

Comment: @aga Sir : Okay okay . Actually i follow this . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found my mistake in app id where the package name was incorrect and during build the debug/manifest and release/manifest would take the package name from there only, no matter what.

My solution was: File->Project Structure->in Modules, app ->Flavours -> applicationId, I corrected applicationId and it worked perfectly.